# ipyleaflet not showing map in JupyterLab

Tags: mapping, jupyter-notebook

I've done conda install *ipyleaflet* and then *conda install -c conda-forge ipyleaflet* but when I run:

```
import ipyleaflet
map1 = ipyleaflet.Map(zoom=3, layout={'height':'400px'})
dc = ipyleaflet.DrawControl()
map1.add_control(dc)
map1
```

I just get an output kernel that says:

> Map(center=[0.0, 0.0], controls=(ZoomControl(options=['position', 'zoom_in_text', 'zoom_in_title', 'zoom_out_t…

and no map shows up.

Does anyone know how to get ipyleaflet map to show up in JupyterLab?

Comment: I found the answer from this page: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html